# Text size Epson TM-H5000II

Tags: java, epson, escpos

I'm trying to reduce the size of the text, according to the manual i need to use the ESC ! 1 (https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=23) but i dont know how to pass it to java code, i try define a bite and use decimal, hex and ASCII but doesnt work.

```
public class JavaPrinter implements PrinterApi {
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JavaPrinter.class);

PrintService printService;
boolean isFile = false;
String printerName = null;
PrintStream prnStr;
private PipedInputStream pipe;
PipedOutputStream dataOutput;
Doc mydoc;

byte[] widthNormal = { 0x1b, '!', '1' };
@Override
public void setNormal() {
    if (isFile)
        return;
    try {
        prnStr.write(widthNormal);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new DeviceServerRuntimeException("", e);
    }
}
```

Above is part of the code i write, i appreciate any advice, help! THX

Comment: Your code is not a minimal working example of the problem you are describing, which is that formatting is not being applied to text (downvote was not from me, but is justified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `1` as a number with the `ESC !` command to change from the larger Font A to the smaller Font B in ESC/POS.

You also need to follow it with some text and a newline, which I can't see in your example. A self-contained Java example would look like this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class FontChangeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        byte[] reset = {0x1b, '@'};
        byte[] fontA = {0x1b, '!', 0x00};
        byte[] fontB = {0x1b, '!', 0x01};

        try(FileOutputStream outp = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/lp0")) {
            outp.write(reset);
            outp.write("Font A\n".getBytes());
            outp.write(fontB);
            outp.write("Font B\n".getBytes());
            outp.write(fontA);
            outp.write("Font A again\n".getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

Which displays this on a TM-T20II:

[image: Example output]

This assumes that your setup is otherwise functioning, and is capable of shipping binary data to your printer.

Comment: Ty for your answer, why is the /n important? I try with your code, and some other code that i found in other question, and doesn't work without the /n